# Java error on sort program

Tags: java, sorting

I'm getting an error that I can't track down or solve.

```
/**
     * Problem 23.13
     * ExcutionTimeForSorting class obtains the execution time
     * of selection sort, bubble sort, merge sort, quick sort, heap sort,
     * and radiz sort for input size 5,000, 10,000, 15,000, 20,000,
     * 25,000, and 30,000.
     */

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.*;


    public class ExecutionTimeForSorting
    {
        //start of main method
        public static void main (String [] args)
        {
            //creating a two-dimensional array for selection sort
            int [] [] selectionArray = new int [6] [];
            selectionArray[0] = new int [50000];
            selectionArray[1] = new int [100000];
            selectionArray[2] = new int [150000];
            selectionArray[3] = new int [200000];
            selectionArray[4] = new int [250000];
            selectionArray[5] = new int [300000];

            //creating a two-dimensional array for bubble sort
            int [] [] bubbleArray = new int [6] [];
            bubbleArray[0] = new int [50000];
            bubbleArray[1] = new int [100000];
            bubbleArray[2] = new int [150000];
            bubbleArray[3] = new int [200000];
            bubbleArray[4] = new int [250000];
            bubbleArray[5] = new int [300000];

            //creating a two-dimensional array for merge sort
            int [] [] mergeArray = new int [6] [];
            mergeArray[0] = new int [50000];
            mergeArray[1] = new int [100000];
            mergeArray[2] = new int [150000];
            mergeArray[3] = new int [200000];
            mergeArray[4] = new int [250000];
            mergeArray[5] = new int [300000];

            //creating a two-dimensional array for quick sort
            int [] [] quickArray = new int [6] [];
            quickArray[0] = new int [50000];
            quickArray[1] = new int [100000];
            quickArray[2] = new int [150000];
            quickArray[3] = new int [200000];
            quickArray[4] = new int [250000];
            quickArray[5] = new int [300000];

            //creating a two-dimensional array for heap sort
            int [] [] heapArray = new int [6] [];
            heapArray[0] = new int [50000];
            heapArray[1] = new int [100000];
            heapArray[2] = new int [150000];
            heapArray[3] = new int [200000];
            heapArray[4] = new int [250000];
            heapArray[5] = new int [300000];

            //creating a two-dimensional array for radix sort
            int [] [] radixArray = new int [6] [];
            radixArray[0] = new int [50000];
            radixArray[1] = new int [100000];
            radixArray[2] = new int [150000];
            radixArray[3] = new int [200000];
            radixArray[4] = new int [250000];
            radixArray[5] = new int [300000];

            //declaring two variables to find elapsed time
            long startTime = 0, endTime = 0;

            //creating one-dimensional array to store elapsed times
            long [] selectionExecutionTime = new long [6];
            long [] bubbleExecutionTime = new long [6];
            long [] mergeExecutionTime = new long [6];
            long [] quickExecutionTime = new long [6];
            long [] heapExecutionTime = new long [6];
            long [] radixExecutionTime = new long [6];

            //storing the same integers randomly in all two-dimensional arrays
            for (int i = 0; i < selectionArray.length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < selectionArray[i].length; j++)
                {
                    int number = (int) (Math.random() * 1000);
                    selectionArray[i][j] = number;
                    bubbleArray[i][j] = number;
                    mergeArray[i][j] = number;
                    quickArray[i][j] = number;
                    heapArray[i][j] = number;
                    radixArray[i][j] = number;
                }
            }

            //finding the elapsed time for selection sort
            for (int i = 0; i < selectionArray.length; i++)
            {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                //call to selectionSort method
                SelectionSort.selectionSort(selectionArray[i]);
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                selectionExecutionTime[i] = endTime - startTime;
                startTime = 0;
                endTime = 0;
            }

            //finding the elapsed time for bubble sort
            for (int i = 0; i < bubbleArray.length; i++)
            {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                //call to BubbleSort method
                BubbleSort.bubbleSort(selectionArray[i]);
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                bubbleExecutionTime[i] = endTime - startTime;
                startTime = 0;
                endTime = 0;
            }

            //finding the elapsed time for merge sort
            for (int i = 0; i < mergeArray.length; i++)
            {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                //call to mergeSort method
                MergeSort.mergeSort(selectionArray[i]);
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                mergeExecutionTime[i] = endTime - startTime;
                startTime = 0;
                endTime = 0;
            }

            //finding the elapsed time for quick sort
            for (int i = 0; i < quickArray.length; i++)
            {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                //call to quickSort method
                QuickSortNonRecursive.quickSort(selectionArray[i]);
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                quickExecutionTime[i] = endTime - startTime;
                startTime = 0;
                endTime = 0;
            }

            //finding the elapsed time for heap sort
            for (int i = 0; i < heapArray.length; i++)
            {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                //call to heapSort method
                HeapSort.heapSort(selectionArray[i]);
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                heapExecutionTime[i] = endTime - startTime;
                startTime = 0;
                endTime = 0;
            }

            //finding the elapsed time for radix sort
            for (int i = 0; i < radixArray.length; i++)
            {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                //call to radixSort method
                RadixSort.radixSort(selectionArray[i]);
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                radixExecutionTime[i] = endTime - startTime;
                startTime = 0;
                endTime = 0;
            }

            /*displaying all elapsed times of all sorting techniques
            in a table format */
            System.out.printf("%10s%2s%15s%13s%13s%13s%13s%13\n",
                    "Array size", "|", "Selection Sort", "Bubble Sort",
                    "Merge Sort", "Quick Sort", "Heap Sort", "Radix Sort");

            System.out.println("-----------|-----------------" +
                    "-------------------------------------------" +
                    "---------------------");

            for (int i = 0; i < selectionArray.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.printf("%7s%5s%13s%14s%13s%13s%13s%13s\n",
                        selectionArray[i].length, "|",
                        selectionExecutionTime[i],
                        bubbleExecutionTime[i],
                        mergeExecutionTime[i],
                        quickExecutionTime[i],
                        heapExecutionTime[i],
                        radixExecutionTime[i]);
            }
        }//end of main method


    }//end of ExecutionTimeForSorting class

    //SelectionSort Class demonstrates selectionSort method
    class SelectionSort
    {
        //the method for sorting the numbers
        public static void selectionSort (int[] list)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length -1; i++)
            {
                //finding the minimum in the list
                int currentMin = list[i];
                int currentMinIndex = i;

                for (int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++)
                {
                    if (currentMin > list[j])
                    {
                        currentMin = list[j];
                        currentMinIndex = j;
                    }
                }

                //swapping list[i] with list [currentMinIndex] if necessary
                if (currentMinIndex != i)
                {
                    list[currentMinIndex] = list[i];
                    list[i] = currentMin;
                }
            }
        }//end of selectionSort method
    }//end of SelectionSort class

    //BubbleSort class demonstrates the method bubbleSort
    class BubbleSort
    {
        //bubble sort method
        public static void bubbleSort(int[] list)
        {
            boolean needNextPass = true;

            for (int k = 1; k < list.length && needNextPass; k++)
            {
                //array may be sorted and next pass not needed
                needNextPass = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < list.length - k; i++)
                {
                    if (list[i] > list [i + 1])
                    {
                        //swap list[i] with list [i+1]
                        int temp = list[i];
                        list[i] = list[i + 1];
                        list[i + 1] = temp;
                        //Next pass still needed
                        needNextPass = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }//end of bubbleSort method
    }//end of BubbleSort class


    //MergeSort class demonstrates the methods mergeSort and merge
    class MergeSort
    {
        //the method for sorting the numbers
        public static void mergeSort (int[] list)
        {
            if (list.length > 1)
            {
                //merge sort the first half
                int[] firstHalf = new int[list.length/2];
                System.arraycopy(list, 0, firstHalf, 0, list.length/2);
                mergeSort(firstHalf);

                //merge sort the second half
                int secondHalfLength = list.length - list.length/2;
                int[] secondHalf = new int[secondHalfLength];
                System.arraycopy(list, list.length/2, secondHalf, 0, secondHalfLength);
                mergeSort(secondHalf);

                //merge first half with second half into list
                merge (firstHalf, secondHalf, list);
            }
        }//end of mergeSort method

        //merge two sorted lists
        public static void merge (int[] list1, int[] list2, int[] temp)
        {
            int current1 = 0;//current index in list1
            int current2 = 0;//current index in list2
            int current3 = 0;//current index in temp

            while(current1 < list1.length && current2 < list2.length)
            {
                if (list1[current1] < list2[current2])
                    temp[current3++] = list1[current1++];
                else
                    temp[current3++] = list2[current2++];
            }

            while (current1 < list1.length)
                temp [current3++] = list1[current1++];

            while (current2 < list2.length)
                temp[current3++] = list2[current2++];
        }//end of merge method
    }//end of MergeSort class


    /*QuickSortNonRecursice class demonstrates the mehods quickSort,
    quickSort helper and partition*/
    class QuickSortNonRecursive
    {
        //quickSort method
        public static void quickSort(int[] list)
        {
            quickSort(list, 0, list.length - 1);
        }//end of quickSort method

        //quickSort helper method
        public static void quickSort (int[] list, int first, int last)
        {
            //creating a stack of integers
            Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
            stack.push(first);
            stack.push(last);

            while(!stack.empty())
            {
                last = (Integer)stack.pop();
                first = (Integer)stack.pop();

                if(last <= first)
                    continue;

                //get the pivot point
                int pivotIndex = partition(last, first, last);

                if((pivotIndex - first) > (last - pivotIndex))
                {
                    stack.push(first);
                    stack.push(pivotIndex - 1);
                }

                stack.push(pivotIndex + 1);
                stack.push(last);

                if ((last - pivotIndex) >= (pivotIndex - first))
                {
                    stack.push(first);
                    stack.push(pivotIndex - 1);
                }
            }
        }//end of quickSort helper method

        //partition the array list[first...last]
        private static int partition(int[] list, int first, int last)
        {
            //choose the first element as the pivot
            int pivot = list[first];
            int low = first +1;//index for forward search
            int high = last;//index for backward search

            while (high > low)
            {
                //search forward from left
                while (low <= high && list[low] <= pivot)
                    low++;

                //search backward from right
                while( low <= high && list[high] > pivot)
                    high--;

                //swap two elements in the list
                if (high > low)
                {
                    int temp = list[high];
                    list[high] = list[low];
                    list[low] = temp;
                }
            }

            while(high > first && list[high] >= pivot)
                high--;

            //swap pivot with list[high]
            if (pivot > list[high])
            {
                list[first] = list[high];
                list[high] = pivot;
            }
            else
            {
                return first;
            }
        }//end of partition method
    }//end of QuickSortNonRecursive class


    //HeapSort class demonstrates the method heapSort
    class HeapSort
    {
        //heap sort method
        public static <E extends Comparable> void heapSort (E[] list)
        {
            //creating a heap of integers
            Heap<E> heap = new Heap<E>();

            //adding elements to the heap
            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
                heap.add(list[i]);

            //remove elements from the heap
            for (int i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                list[i] = heap.remove();

            }//end of heapSort method
    }//end of HeapSort class


    /*RadixSort class demonsrates the methods radixSort, radixSort
    helper, and getPosition*/
    class RadixSort
    {
        //radixSort method
        public static void radixSort (int[] list)
        {
            radixSort(list,5);
        }//end of radixSort method

        //radixSort helper method
        public static void radixSort (int[] list, int mostDigits)
        {
            ArrayList<Integer>[] radix = new ArrayList[10];

            for (int i = 0; i < radix.length; i++)
            {
                radix[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            }

            for (int index = 0; index < list.length; index++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < radix.length; i++)
                {
                    radix[i].clear();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
                {
                    int position = getPosition(list[i],
                            index);
                    radix[position].add(list[i]);
                }

                int k = 0; //index of list
                for (int i = 0; i < radix.length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j< radix[i].size(); j++)
                        list[k++] = radix[i].get(j);
                }
            }
        }//end of radixSort helper method

        //getPosition method
        public static int getPosition(int value, int index)
        {
            int result = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
                result = result * 10;
            return (value / result) % 10;
        }//end of getPosition method
    }//end of RadixSort class
```

The error I'm getting is attached...
[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWYXH.jpg):

Comment: `javascript !=== java`

Comment: You took a photo of your monitor and uploaded that?

Comment: Yes. PrtScrn key on kb inop!

Comment: Hey Chalen, welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a read of [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and consider posting a [mcve] to make it easier for people looking through your code.

Comment: Each of the reports errors has multiple duplicates. Search them on SO or on a search page and fix them one after another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First error:
I could be wrong, but it looks like your heapSort method only works with items that implement the Comparable interface, which means you need to use the Integer class rather than the int primitive type. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Second error:
You're passing "last" as your first parameter to partition() instead of "list".

Third error: 
You're trying to declare an object of type Heap, but you never define a Heap class. I'm not aware of any native class called Heap in Java.

Comment: Thanks Robert M. It's going MUCH smoother now. I think those got me back on the right track!

I will review more of the forum rules to learn how to make easier to read posts in the future. Thanks all for your help and corrections!